# Authenticating ajax queries in CouchDB with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb

When accessing a localhost's protected CouchDB database via `$.ajax`, it prompts an alert asking for the username/password. If i cancel the prompt, CouchDB alerts an error and my $.ajax error callback is never executed. If i pass in an authorized user to the url (`http://user:pass@local...`), the `success` callback is executed properly.

So, is possible to make authenticated ajax queries to Couch and use my own error handling functions?

**Edit, code:**

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(){
          console.log("ok");
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log("error");
        }
      });
```

- If `myUrl` does not include credentials, like `http://localhost:5984/mydb/handshakeDoc`, error callback is never executed after cancelling the prompt.
- If `myUrl` include invalid credentials, like `http://user:invalidpass@localhost:5984/mydb/handshakeDoc`, error prompt still appears and error callback is never executed after cancelling the prompt.
- If `myUrl` include valid credentials, success callback is executed

Comment: To clarify - Does $.ajax.error only not get called when you cancel the prompt? What happens if you enter invalid credentials into the prompt?

And please post your code.

Comment: if i enter invalid credentials, prompt still appears. Code updated.

Comment: Are you even sending any data to the url? And what is the handshakeDoc api method - I can't find it in the couchdb documentations.

Comment: handshakeDoc is just a document example. data is not needed to perform a success or error connection with the database (I'm just setting the jsonp dataType to allow cross-origin)

Answer (score 0):

----- possible solution -----

So, I got a solution that worked for me. However I had to use apache as a Proxy server to circumvent the cross origin policy.

The idea here is to remove the problems with the cross domain policy and use an http-server to proxy our request locally to the couchdb service. Every request for example.com/couch will be redirected to the couchdb service. That way you don't have to use a jsonp request anymore.

The initial problem you asked about whether or not you can use your own error handling is directly linked to jsonp requests in jQuery as they do not use the error handlers - They never get called at all.

Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyPass           /couch      http://localhost:5984
    ProxyPassReverse    /couch      http://localhost:5984
</VirtualHost>
```

jQuery ajax request:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/couch",
    dataType: "json",
 }).done(function() {console.log("done");})
   .fail(function() {console.log("fail");})
   .always(function() {console.log("always");});
});
```

----- Original post -----

You could try this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    type: "GET",
    username: user,
    password: pass,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(){
      console.log("ok");
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
```

jQuery gives you the possibility to use the http basic auth via two ajax parameters (username and password).

Or you might wanna try the [CouchDB jQuery plugin](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/).

Comment: thanks but already tried using the username/password, with no luck (not even using correct credentials)

Comment: yeah, it just prompt the login alert

Comment: And what error are you getting from couchdb? Is jsonp supported and enabled? DO you even have to use jsonp?

Comment: jsonp its needed as couchdb is running in different port that the JS making the ajax request, and is enabled in CouchDB configuration. On the error, CouchDB just prompts another alert saying that auhtentication is required.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem - jsonP requests aren't made with the XMLHttpRequest object and henceforth don't support the username/password parameters and normal basic auth. I'm looking for a viable solution.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying some possible solutions also. If i find something i will post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37118/discussion-between-louis-h-and-tmichel)

Comment: sadly i can not chat through corporate proxy